# laravel/ui[v3.2.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^8.0

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-7, laravel-ui

I try to install:

> composer require laravel/ui

But i Keep receive this error:

> laravel/ui[v3.2.0, ..., 3.x-dev] require illuminate/console ^8.0 -> found illuminate/console[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/ui ^3.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v3.2.0, 3.x-dev].
> and here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8|^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in laravel. Hope anyone provide the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? You are using an outdated version of Laravel, and the package you want to require is not compatible with that "old" version

Comment: Sounds like it's conflicting with other packages you have installed.  I had a similar issue and realized that I had to update my Telescope package to get the composer command to work.  Try composing an older version and see if you get the same error: "composer require laravel/ui:^2.0"

Comment: I bet many of us will continue using an 'outdated' version of Laravel. Not everyone wants to divert valuable business development time to reading about new laravel stuff that they don't really need.

Comment: composer require laravel/ui:^3.*
this is the perfect solution

Answer (score 32):

I used this:

```
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```

instead of

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

and it worked!
according to this laravel document [link]: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend

Comment: If you have Laravel 8, try to update your packages with:
   composer update
then run again:
   composer require laravel/ui 
and it should work

Answer (score 5):

According to Laravel framework documentation use this command

Laravel **8.*** in requires laravel/ui version **3.4**

```
composer require laravel/ui:^3.4
```

Laravel **7.** in requires laravel/ui version **2.4**

```
composer require laravel/ui:^2.4
```

Laravel **6.*** in requires specific laravel/ui version **1.0**

```
composer require laravel/ui:^1.0 --dev
```

[Laravel 7 UI documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/frontend)

[Laravel 6 UI documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend)

Answer (score 1):

You must update your packages with :

```
composer update
```

then you can run :

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/ui:*" to figure out if any version is installable

> "composer require laravel/ui:*"